# How to use javascript to change text color based on item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am creating a website for a snow cone stand and I would like to do something fun with their flavor list using javascript. I want to change text listing the flavor to the appropriate color of the actual fruit. How could I do this using Javascript? Currently I have the flavor list in arrays and I am inserting the HTML into the page using my addToPage function. How can I create an array of colors and color the text based on fruit? Thanks.

```
var flavorAdder = (function() {

var flavorArr1, flavorArr2, flavorArr3, flavorArr4, textLocator1, textLocator2, textLocator3, textLocator4, addToPage;

flavorArr1 = [
    '<p>Apple</p>',
    '<p>Banana</p>',
    '<p>Birthday Cake</p>',
    '<p>Black Cherry</p>'
];

flavorArr2 = [
    '<p>Green Apple</p>',
    '<p>Guava</p>',
    '<p>Honeydew Melon</p>',
    '<p>Huckleberry</p>'
];

flavorArr3 = [
    '<p>Peach</p>',
    '<p>Piña Coloda</p>',
    '<p>Pineapple</p>',
    '<p>Pink Grapefruit</p>'
];

flavorArr4 = [
    '<p>Pink Lemonade</p>',
    '<p>Red Raspberry</p>',
    '<p>Rootbeer</p>'
];

textLocator1 = document.querySelector('#flavorList1');
textLocator2 = document.querySelector('#flavorList2');
textLocator3 = document.querySelector('#flavorList3');
textLocator4 = document.querySelector('#flavorList4');


addToPage = function(arr, text) {
    arr.forEach(function(current) {
        text.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', current);
    });
}

addToPage(flavorArr1, textLocator1);
addToPage(flavorArr2, textLocator2);
addToPage(flavorArr3, textLocator3);
addToPage(flavorArr4, textLocator4);


})();
```

Comment: did my answer help??

Comment: Yes thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can add a css class to the flavour array like this:

```
flavorArr1 = [
    '<p class="green">Apple</p>',
    '<p class="yellow">Banana</p>',
    '<p class="pink">Birthday Cake</p>',
    '<p class="cherry">Black Cherry</p>'
];
```

And then in a css/sass file:

```
.green {
    color: green;
}
.cherry {
    color: red;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding classes and then defining the styling based on the class would be the easiest solution.

```
flavorArr1 = [
    '<p class="red">Apple</p>',
    '<p class="yellow">Banana</p>',
    '<p class="wheat">Birthday Cake</p>',
    '<p class="crimson">Black Cherry</p>'
];

flavorArr2 = [
    '<p class="lime">Green Apple</p>',
    '<p class="GreenYellow">Guava</p>',
    '<p class="DarkOrange">Honeydew Melon</p>',
    '<p class="MediumVioletRed">Huckleberry</p>'
];
```

**CSS: either embedded or stylesheet**

```
<style>
.red{color:red;}
.yellow{color:yellow;}
.wheat{color:wheat;}
.crimson{color:crimson;}
.DarkOrange{color:DarkOrange;}
.MediumVioletRed{color:MediumVioletRed;}
.lime{color:lime;}
.GreenYellow{color:GreenYellow;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the color by javascript you can remove and add new classes

```
var cherry = document.getElementById("cherry");
cherry.classList.remove("red");
cherry.classList.add("yellow");
```

css:

```
.yellow {
    color: yellow;
}
.red {
    color: red;
}
```